# How do I add dns key to https://dlv.isc.org?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, named-conf

I am trying to set up DNSSEC.

I am following this how-to:
[How to from ISC Web Site](https://dlv.isc.org/about/using)

However, when I try to paste in any line from dlvset-thelinuxgeek.org. and dsset-thelinuxgeek.org., I get the following error from the ISC web site:

> No DNSKEY found in the zone for this DLV / DS record.

Any idea what I missed / did wrong?

Comment: Looks like you've fixed this yourself as I can see DLV records for your zone. I was going to answer your question by saying that the DLV system is querying for DNSKEY records that match the DNSKEY/DS/DLV records you pasted into the "Add Record" form, but not finding them. This would most likely be due to negative caching somewhere. By the way, Dreamhost supposedly support DS records ([link](http://www.pir.org/get/registrars?order=field_dnssec_value&sort=desc)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this.  I needed the output from these files instead:
Kthelinuxgeek.org.+005+32074.key
Kthelinuxgeek.org.+005+56340.key